# Error 1004: Unable to get the Search property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I am repeatedly getting error 1004: Unable to get the Search property of the WorksheetFunction class for the code below. Basically, I am trying to ascertain if each cell in a specified range contains a value that meets a criteria - if this criteria is met, then a category should be assigned to the value in another cell in the same worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Lookup_Category()

Dim Cell As Range, Narration As Range
Dim Counter As Integer

Set Narration = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each Cell In Narration

    Select Case Cell
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("LICIOUS", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Licious"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("BILLDESK.ELECTRICITY", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Electricity"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("PLAYSTATIONNETWO", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "PlayStation"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("NEFT CR", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Inbound Transfers"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("IMPS", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Inbound Transfers"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("IB FUNDS TRANSFER CR", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Inbound Transfers"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("IB BILLPAY DR-HDFCYA-463917XXXXXX5057", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Credit Card Payment"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("POS 416021XXXXXX5159 SWIGGY", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Dining"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("POS 416021XXXXXX5159 SWIGGY DASH", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Groceries"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("UPI-VODAFONE IDEA LTD-VILPOSKAR", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Mobile Bill"
            Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("UPI-SS LIQOURS", Cell) > 1
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Alcohol"
            Case VBA.Left(Cell.Value, 3) = "REV"
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = "Refunds"
            Case Else
                 Cells(Cell.Row, 8) = ""
    End Select
 
Next Cell
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any blank cells in that column?

Comment: No, there aren't any blank cells.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Cell.Address` return in the Immediate Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't need to be VBA, and I'd recommend against VBA if it's not necessary.  Say you have a data setup like this:

[image]

Column B is the text you're searching against, and column H is where you want the output (to match what the code does).  I have created a table in columns M and N (though it could be anywhere, even on a different sheet) that contains what you're looking for and what a match should return.

In cell H2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,3)="REV","Refund",IFERROR(INDEX($N$2:$N$12,MATCH(999,SEARCH($M$2:$M$12,B2))),""))
```

If it absolutely must be VBA, then I recommend using `Select Case True` against the `Like` operator, like so:

```
Sub Lookup_Category()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook:         Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet:        Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Dim rNarration As Range:    Set rNarration = ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    If rNarration.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub 'No data in range

    Dim rCell As Range, rTarget As Range, sValue As String
    For Each rCell In rNarration.Cells
        Set rTarget = ws.Cells(rCell.Row, 8)
        sValue = UCase(rCell.Value)
        Select Case True
            Case sValue Like "*LICIOUS*":                               rTarget.Value = "Licious"
            Case sValue Like "*BILLDESK.ELECTRICITY*":                  rTarget.Value = "Electricity"
            Case sValue Like "*PLAYSTATIONNETWO*":                      rTarget.Value = "PlayStation"
            Case sValue Like "*NEFT CR*":                               rTarget.Value = "Inbound Transfers"
            Case sValue Like "*IMPS*":                                  rTarget.Value = "Inbound Transfers"
            Case sValue Like "*IB FUNDS TRANSFER CR*":                  rTarget.Value = "Inbound Transfers"
            Case sValue Like "*IB BILLPAY DR-HDFCYA-463917XXXXXX5057*": rTarget.Value = "Credit Card Payment"
            Case sValue Like "*POS 416021XXXXXX5159 SWIGGY DASH*":      rTarget.Value = "Groceries"
            Case sValue Like "*POS 416021XXXXXX5159 SWIGGY*":           rTarget.Value = "Dining"
            Case sValue Like "*UPI-VODAFONE IDEA LTD-VILPOSKAR*":       rTarget.Value = "Mobile Bill"
            Case sValue Like "*UPI-SS LIQOURS*":                        rTarget.Value = "Alcohol"
            Case Left(sValue, 3) = "REV":                               rTarget.Value = "Refunds"
            Case Else:                                                  rTarget.ClearContents
        End Select
    Next rCell
 
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree that VBA isn't necessary, but my aim was to practice and figure out what works in VBA and what does not. The code you've provided does provide me with the intended result, but I was trying to figure out what exactly was causing the error in my code - I'd be really thankful if you could shed any insight on it.

Comment: @VarunKapur The error is caused by `WorksheetFunction.Search` because it's testing the cell for each case, and if the cell doesn't contain even one of the values, the Search function will return an error `#VALUE!` and without error handling, your code just errors out.  This is why best practice is to have VB functions in VB.  The equivalent would be `InStr` which will instead return a 0 if the text isn't found instead of an error.